# Removing text from an output after a character

Tags: jquery

When processing a table with this function:

```
*$("tablelist div.panel",html).each(function( index ) {/*loop-start*/
    var job = {};/*init*/
    job.title = ($(this).text());
});/*loop-end*/*
```

I get as a result:

**Text 1-Text2-Text3-Text4.**

However, I just want **Text 1** as a result. I don't want all the text after the first **-**.

I've tried many ways without success. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var str = "Text 1-Text2-Text3-Text4"
str.substr(0,str.indexOf("-"))
```

It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `substring` and `indexOf`:

```
var text = 'Text 1-Text2-Text3-Text4';

alert(text.substring(0, text.indexOf('-')));
```

`substring` will get the substring from `0`th index to the `indexOf` index.

Comment: Please explain the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can split it on `-` and take the first element. `String.split` returns an array, whose first element at 0 index will give you the text you want.

(Remember indexes start from 0, so first is 0, second is 1 and so on).

```
job.title = $(this).text().split('-')[0];
```

Comment: I think this will be slower as compared to `substring`